# Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object

Tags: java, sql-server, windows-7, jboss

We are trying to increase the scope of database compatibility for our web application. Our application is Java EE with JSP, Servlets, and EJBs. The database we are trying to make our application compatible with is SQL Server 2008.

The problem we are running into occurs in our application when a user attempts to attach more than one file on a particular screen with an interface for multiple uploads. The user can successfully attach the first file and the database updates correctly. When the user attempts to update after adding the second attachment a Unique Key constraint violation [Cannot insert Duplicate value] error is thrown.  The following is the error that is output:

`Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__Key__8861A9F23EDC53F0'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Entity'.
org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not insert: [foo.beans.eproc.entity.Entity]`

Thus far we have tried the following to resolve the problem:

1. Add constructors to the entities that maintain the UQ Key constraint in order to initialize the records to be unique and non-null. This has resolved previous issues with other key constraint violations.
2. We have read of an issue with Hibernate executing INSERTS before DELETES.  Earlier, we thought this may be causing the issue. Currently, as part of the update process, all stored attachments are removed and all current attachments in the session are added to the database. Our thought was that if it really is trying to perform the INSERTS before DELETES than it would throw a UQ Key violation with the attachments.
3. If we just delete the UQ keys in SQL Server and the add a second attachment the database updates without a problem and it does not appear to have any non-unique data contained in the records.

Unfortunately, [1] above did not resolve the problem as the UQ Key violation is still being thrown.  For [2] above, we have been unable to verify that Hiberante is executing the INSERTS before the DELETES.

Answers to the following questions would help us make some progress:

1. Could removing the unique keys in SQL server be a potential solution to this problem?
2. Is there is a way to verify that Hibernate is or is not executing INSERTS before DELETES? If so, how might we check that?
3. If there is a problem with Hibernate in the above case, how might we resolve this problem?

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#configuration-optional: hibernate.show_sql - Write all SQL statements to console. This is an alternative to setting the log category org.hibernate.SQL to debug.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the table definition and the value of the unique key column(s) after the error is issued.

Answer (score 1):

1) It could be a solution, but, if you need that constraint to ensure unique values, then you're losing it. Also, for what it's worth, unique constraints are used by the query optimizer to make queries run faster, so that loss could hurt performance as well as a data integrity.

2) There are nhibernate monitoring tools, but, there are also TSQL monitoring tools. If you're using SQL SErver 2008 or better run an extended events session and capture the queries called through rpc complete and sql batch complete events. SQL Server 2005 & earlier you can do the same with a server-side trace set up through Profiler.

3) Don't know Hibernate well enough to comment here, sorry.